# аргумент типа long long несовместим с параметром типа LPVOID

Tags: c++, c++11

```
VirtualProtect(0x1E61E2CFD24, 0x7ffffff, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, NULL);
```

аргумент типа long long несовместим с параметром типа LPVOID

Comment: Есть определенные сомнения... Почему именно `0x1E61E2CFD24`, а не указатель? Т.е. - то ли вы вообще делаете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
VirtualProtect((LPVOID)0x1E61E2CFD24, 0x7ffffff, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, NULL);
```